# Check if window is scrolled at a specific position - WebdriverJS + Jasmine

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

I am using `Selenium`, `WebDriverJS` and `Jasmine` to write and end-to-end test for my web-page. In this part of the code, I want to check that when a button is clicked the window is correctly scrolled to the top of the `html` page. This is the function that I want to check:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},600);
        return false;
    });
});
```

And this is the test I have written to test it:

```
it('should enable to click on the logo to get back to the top of the page', function() {

    // Header's logo should not be displayed in the page
    this.driver.sleep(this.driver.executeScript('onload'));
    var logoHeader = this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.scrollToTop img'));
    logoHeader.isDisplayed().then(function(present) {
        expect(present).not.toBe(true);
    });

    // Header's logo should be displayed in the page when window is scrolled
    this.driver.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', logoHeader);
    logoHeader.isDisplayed();

    // When clicking on the button, page should be scrolled up to the beginning
    logoHeader.click();
    this.driver.manage().window().getPosition().then(function(position) {
        expect(position).toBe({ x: 0, y: 0});
    });
});
```

But then when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Message:
    Expected Object({ x: 0, y: 23 }) to be Object({ x: 0, y: 0 }).
```

Do you know what is the issue with my code or do you have a tutorial to look at with a similar example?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Do you get the same error all the time with same object? Or does it vary? Also when the click happens does it scroll to the top of the page?

Comment: I get it only with this object. When I target a different button, I just use `driver.get(http://localhost:8000/#section)` and it goes well. And yes, when you click on the image, it goes to the top of the image via the `scrollTop` function.

Comment: I meant do you get same error all the time whenever you run the same test script multiple times, or does `{ x: 0, y: 23 }` vary in your error statement?

Comment: I tried in different script, by also applying a scroll in different tests, and I get the same error.

Comment: Then its not the problem of selenium or the automation code. When you click on the logo it is scrolling to the location `{ x: 0, y: 23 }` and not to `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`. 23px on the y direction isn't much of a problem anyways. As far as i know your selenium code is working as required. Can you check if `scrollTop()` scrolls the page to some element like header or body, etc... or it scrolls it to a proper 0,0 coordinates?

Comment: It doesn't, apparently the window can't scroll to `0,0` coordinates. I guess there's something wrong inside the code that needs to be re-written.